# Graph API - Temporary Access Pass Generation

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

Have the following script that is trying to create a csv of TAP codes using the Graph API.
Currently getting an Error 401 Unathorised error when reaching `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
<# Region Auth Start #>
$tenantId = "REDACTED"
$clientID = "REDACTED"
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$redirectUri = "https://localhost"
$TokenResponse = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -TenantId $tenantId -Interactive -RedirectUri $redirectUri -Scopes $Scope
<# Region Auth End #>


<# Region Generate AAD TAP Start #>
 
#Import users from csv file
###########################
$users = (Import-csv -Path "c:\Temp\users.csv").UserName
 
#Initializing Hash table to store output
########################################
$hash = @{} 
 
#Looping through each user to generate AAD TAP
##############################################
 
ForEach ($user in $users) {
    $Headers = @{Authorization = "$($TokenResponse.token_type) $($TokenResponse.access_token)"}
    $tapUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/$user/authentication/temporaryAccessPassMethods"
    $body = "{}"
    $tapResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $tapUri -Body $body -Method POST -ContentType "application/json"
    $tap = $tapResponse.temporaryAccessPass
    $hash.add($user,$tap)
}
 
#Saving result to file
######################
 
$outpath = "C:\Temp\Results.csv"
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property @{N='User Name';E={$_.Key}}, @{N='Temporary Access Pass';E={$_.Value}} |Export-csv -Path $outpath -NoTypeInformation
 
<# Region Generate AAD TAP End #>
```

Any ideas as to what the route cause could be would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I believe that `Get-MSALToken` returns a [`Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.authenticationresult?view=azure-dotnet) object, meaning that it should be `$TokenResponse.AccessToken` and `$TokenResponse.TokenType`. I would just confirm what your `$Headers` look like and whether you have the necessary permissions for the [Graph endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/temporaryaccesspassauthenticationmethod-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions-acting-on-other-users).

Comment: One thing you should definitely confirm is whether you can carry out the action in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) on another user. As an aside, you could also try out the [`Microsoft.Graph PowerShell module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-beta) too.

Comment: Appreciate the input, tried adjusting headers to no avail. Appreciate the input, just dont really know how to go about it myself. Will take a deeper dive based on the material you've suggested. Many thanks

Comment: Are you printing `$Headers` out to screen to make sure it is what you expect it to be? If the token is correctly added, then it's most likely the delegated permissions are not correct for Graph. Just another small note, you probably don't need to specify an empty body for the request or the parameter. You should be able to make a `POST` request without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to generate temporary access pass codes for the users imported in csv using microsoft graph module in powershell in my environment and able to generate TAP codes for the user members successully.

- But before that please make sure you are having global admin rights
  to generate taps and `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` ,
  `User.ReadWrite.All` application and delegated permissions granted
  before executing.- and install graph module to use it.

**Powershell:**

```
$properties = @{}
$properties.isUsableOnce = $True
$properties.startDateTime = '2022-05-05 06:00:00'
$propertiesJSON = $properties | ConvertTo-Json
$hash = @{}
$users = (Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\<path>\filename.csv")

 ForEach ($user in $users) 
 {

New-MgUserAuthenticationTemporaryAccessPassMethod -UserId $user.userPrincipalName -BodyParameter $propertiesJSON
Get-MgUserAuthenticationTemporaryAccessPassMethod -UserId $user.userPrincipalName
$outpath = "C:\Users\....\...\Results.csv"
# $hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property @{N='User Name';E={$_.Key}}, @{N='Temporary Access Pass';E={$_.Value}} |Export-csv -Path $outpath -NoTypeInformation
 
 }
```

**OUTPUT :**
[image]

Reference : [Configure Temporary Access Pass in Azure AD to register Passwordless authentication methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-temporary-access-pass?msclkid=20bd95c6c49611ec823eb350acaf7b13)

If you are trying above using invoke rest method try placing content type in headers and checking the Accesstoken spelling . Also try giving client secret as -ClientSecret   (ConvertTo-SecureString $client_secret -AsPlainText -Force)  in the $tokenResponse

```
$Headers = @{
"Authorization" = " Bearer $($TokenResponse.AccessToken)" 
"Content-type" = "application/json"} 
$body=@{ }
```